# SSIS: How to append SQL Data into an Excel file AT A SPECIFIC ROW

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am designing a SSIS package to export data from a SQL Query into an Excel file, however the column names in the excel file are on row 5.

I have created a Workflow task, and added an OLE DB Source and an Excel Destination, plus a connection manager for both.

The Excel connection manager has a checkbox of 'First row has column names' (See below) - I couldn't find another way to set that to 5 (i.e., fifth row).

I have done some research and some solutions suggested adding some formula to the OpenRowset parameter at CustomerProperties of the Excel Destination.

The above works when the column names are on the first row of the excel-sheet, but what I need to do is to have the column names set on the fifth row; as the first four rows are used for headings:

[image]